# The same vcpkg repository clone used in classic and manifest mode

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, lib, vcpkg

I was using vcpkg in classic mode. Then I found about [vcpkg manifests](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/manifests.html#command-line-interface), I placed a `vcpkg.json` file on my project folder and fired cmake. And the following happened:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.29.1.windows.1")
-- Bootstrapping vcpkg before install
-- Bootstrapping vcpkg before install - failed
CMake Error at C:/Users/user/project/src/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:850 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  C:\Users\user\project\src\mylib\x64\vcpkg-bootstrap.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:121 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
C:\Users\user\project\src\mylib
done
```

It tells me to check `vcpkg-bootstrap.log` but it is empty.

So, am I messing with something or it's not really supported to use vcpkg in manifest mode after it has been used in classic mode?

Or, in other words, do I need a fresh vcpkg git clone to use manifests?

Comment: What version of `vcpkg` do you have? Recent versions are downloaded rather than built locally, so check your connectivity/proxy/etc. Could be permissions problem, too.